# Process html form response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have an html form that looks like this:

```
<form name="form_" method="post" id="contactUs" action="myPage.aspx" enctype="text/plain">
   <input type="text" class="acc_input" name="mail" id="emailadress" />
   <input type="text" class="acc_input" name="name" id="firstName" />
   <input type="button" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Now lets assume that "myPage.aspx" returns "Done" if success or returns "Error" if fails.
I want to display an alert showing the result.
How do i handle the myPage.aspx response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit javascript with the result you want:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Done');</script>")
```